# In Java best way to convert json string with arrays to flat keys

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file with the following structure.

```
    [
   {
      "type":[
         "blog",
         "article",
         "pressrelease"
      ],
      "states":[
         "scheduled",
         "published"
      ],
      "roles":[
         "editor",
         "admin"
      ],
      "actions":[
         "review",
         "delete"
      ]
   },
   {
      "type":[
         "blog",
         "article",
         "pressrelease"
      ],
      "states":[
         "draft",
         "review"
      ],
      "roles":[
         "editor",
         "admin"
      ],
      "actions":[
         "submit",
         "delete"
      ]
   },
   {
      "type":[
         "blog",
         "article"
      ],
      "states":[
         "draft",
         "review"
      ],
      "roles":[
         "author"
      ],
      "actions":[
         "submit"
      ]
   },
   {
      "type":[
         "pressrelease"
      ],
      "states":[
         "draft",
         "review"
      ],
      "roles":[
         "pr",
         "prm"
      ],
      "actions":[
         "submit"
      ]
   },
   {
      "type":[
         "pressrelease"
      ],
      "states":[
         "scheduled",
         "published"
      ],
      "roles":[
         "prm"
      ],
      "actions":[
         "review",
         "delete"
      ]
   }
]
```

I need to write a method that will return actions as per the above json for a given scenario like.

```
getActions(type, state, role){
}
```

I am planning on using GSON to convert the json to list of Action class objects and then build a static map with key as type.state.role and value as list of actions by processing the json with few for loops.
My Map will have

```
"blog.scheduled.editor" : ["review", "delete"]
"blog.scheduled.admin" : ["review", "delete"]
"blog.published.editor" : ["review", "delete"]
```

.....

```
"pressrelease.draft.pr" : ["submit"]
```

So that in getActionas method I can easily return the actions by creating a key from the input values.

I am not sure whether this is the right implementation  or is there utility that will do the job.

Comment: The datastructure should be a tree. And I wouldn't bother with GSON, as you have to match the structure of the JSON *exactly* for it to work. Use the `org.json`-library (or something similar) that can parse a document and gives you access to all elements.

Comment: Use Jackson ObjectMapper to deserialize to raw data (so only List and Map)-->http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#A.22Raw.22_Data_Binding_Example. If you want you could also use it deserialize using full data bindings (but requires to write the exact mapping classes)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but I would suggest using a Tree instead of a Map, since it's the more natural representation of this kind of data.

Construct your tree like this:

```
* [Root]
|___ blog
|   |___ published
|   |   |___ editor
|   |   |   |___ review
|   |   |   |___ delete
|   |   |
|   |   |___ admin
|   |   |   |___ review
|   |   |   |___ delete
|   |   |
|   |
|   |___ scheduled
|   |   |___ admin
|   |   |   |___ delete
|   |   |   |___ review
|   |   |
|   |   |___ editor
|   |   |   |___ review
|   |   |   |___ delete
|   |   |
|   |
|
|___ pressrelease
|   |___ scheduled
|   |   |___ admin
|   |   |   |___ delete
|   |   |   |___ review
(I spend far too much time on that ASCII tree ...)
```

You can then just walk the three "down" from node to node and check the children.

This way, you can also check what states are possible on a blog-entry and (if you re-order or create the tree in a different fashion) you can check what things an admin can do on an article.